# Run/Debug Apache Karaf bundle in Intellj Idea

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf

I want to start develop osgi bundles for Apache Karaf in Intellj Idea. Now i try to run Karaf examples, such as karaf-servlet-example. 
I'm know how run bundle on Karaf from console and deployment folder, but i want do it from Idea by clicking run button. 
I'm just tried to use OSGI configuration with Apache Felix framework, but servlet-example fails on error.

What deployment configuration i must used? Maybe it's any plugin?

Comment: What error does the example fail with? Try to be more specific in the question.

Comment: In osgi deployment configuration i have the same error: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.karaf.examples.karaf-servlet-example-annotation [5](R 5.0): missing requirement [org.apache.karaf.examples.karaf-servlet-example-annotation [5](R 5.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)